# Circle with rectangles inside

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, circles

In this figure our aim is to find radius of the circle.[image]

Note that only $4$ vertices of rectangles are on the circle.

My try: Since the top rectangle side and bottom rectangle side are parallel, From the diagram the distance between these parallel lines is $36$

Let $O$ be the center of the circle which is not known in the diagram.

If $OM$ is perpendicular drawn to top rectangle side and $ON$ is perpendicular drawn to bottom rectangle side then its evident that:

$$OM+ON=36 \tag{1}$$

Let the radius of the circle be $R$

we have a well know formula that length of the chord is given by

$$L=2\sqrt{R^2-x^2}$$ where $x$ is perpendicular length from center to the chord.

So length of bottom rectangle side is $30$ hence

$$2\sqrt{R^2-ON^2}=30 \tag{2}$$

Like wise

$$2\sqrt{R^2-OM^2}=10 \tag{3}$$

Solving $(1)$, $(2)$ and $(3)$ we get $$R=21.37$$

Is this fine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Use the chord theorem of the circle to establish $ 10\cdot20=36\cdot x$. Then, the radius is

$$\sqrt{ \left(\frac{36+x}2\right)^2+ 5^2 } = \sqrt{ \left(\frac{36+\frac{50}9}2\right)^2+ 5^2 }  = \frac{\sqrt{36994}}9=21.37 $$

which verifies your result.